# Using Javascript to embed an onClick event to an HTML div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an interactable and configurable grid using divs as their cells.

To first give a bit of context on this part of the code, I'm basically just repeating td's in HTML output then appending a specific amount of divs into the td's/rows (cellID is just a method for decorating the div names);

```
var table, row, div;
table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i=0; i < rows; i++)
{
    row = document.createElement('td');
    row.id = "row-" + i;
    for (var j=0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = cellID(i, j);
        row.append(div);
    }
    table.append(row);
}
```

Let's say that:
-rows = 4 and -cols = 2  | The output result on the user's end would be this :

[image: Example of what would be shown for a 2x4 grid]

Now my current problem that I'm trying to figure out is how to make every repeated div be given the onClick() event so that an event occurs when you click on the boxes, here is what I tried to make this work :

1. div.addEventListener("click", null);  //This part didn't work for me, though to be honest, I don't really know what to replace the null with
2. div.getElementById(div.id).onclick = function() {  OnClick()  };  (OnClick is a test method to see if it works, however this one just rejects an error, saying that "div.getElementById" is not a function, so I don't know what's up with that.)

These things I tried were all things that had been recommended throughout, but I don't know what else could make it work.

What do you think the problem may be there?

```
-
```

Comment: You're missing `tr` in your table.

Comment: Rows should be `tr`, cells are `td`.

Comment: Gotcha! I will take note of that in the future. And also your answer helped fix the problem in my code, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div.addEventListener()` should work.

But you need to create valid DOM structure. Rows are `tr`, cells are `td`. You can put the `div` in the `td`, or just use the `td` directly.

```js
let rows = 2,
  cols = 4;
var table, row, div;
table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.id = "row-" + i;
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("td");
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = cellID(i, j);
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log('Clicked on', this.id);
    });
    div.innerText = div.id;
    cell.append(div);
    row.append(cell);
  }
  table.append(row);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);

function cellID(i, j) {
  return `cell-${i}-${j}`;
}
```